# Not understanding a claim of Bourbaki about inverse limits in "Theory of Sets"

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In Chapter 7 ("Inverse limits and direct limits"), subchapter 4 ("Conditions for an inverse limit to be non-empty"), Bourbaki lets $(E_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I}$ be a projective system of sets with connecting maps $(f_{\alpha \beta}) _{\alpha, \beta \in I}$, and for each $\alpha \in I$ he lets $\mathfrak S_\alpha$ be a set of subsets of $E_\alpha$ with the property that *"every intersection of sets belonging to $\mathfrak S_\alpha$ also belongs to $\mathfrak S_\alpha$"*. And then he weirdly claims that

> it follows in particular (by considering the intersection of the empty family) that $E_\alpha \in \mathfrak S_\alpha$.

Why should this happen? (This fact is used later in the proof of step 4 of Theorem 1, so it is not a mistype.) It is easy to construct a $\mathfrak S_\alpha$ by choosing $U, V \subsetneq E_\alpha$ and letting $\mathfrak S_\alpha = \{U, V, U \cap V\}$, so that $E_\alpha \notin \mathfrak S_\alpha$ in this example, contradicting Bourbaki.

(By adding one more condition, it seems that Bourbaki wants the $\mathfrak S_\alpha$ to mimick the set of compact subsets of $E_\alpha$ that would exist in a topological setting.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, *why* are you reading Bourbaki's set theory book? (The reason I ask is that it has a number of issues; if you're reading it for historical value, or because you want to read everything Bourbaki wrote, that's one thing, but if your goal is to learn set theory I would strongly recommend against it.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I wouldn't use Bourbaki in order to *learn* anything, not just set theory! I needed a few things about projective limits of sets in order to fully understand the proofs of the results about projective limits of measure spaces (essentially Prokhorov's and Kolmogorov's existence theorems) from the "Integration II" volume.

Comment: Maybe it isn't such a bad idea to learn some (elementary) set theory from Bourbaki. Your problem is resolved in E.II.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those statements which are true vacuously:

- The empty intersection of subsets of a set $A$ is the whole $A$.
- The empty union of subsets of $A$ is an empty set.

In other words: if $\emptyset=\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$ is the empty family of subsets of $A$, then:

$$\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal F}X=A$$

and

$$\bigcup_{X\in\mathcal F}X=\emptyset$$

This is, for example, because $x\in\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal F}X\Longleftrightarrow(\forall X\in\emptyset)x\in X$, which is true for all $x\in A$, again vacuously. ("If you can find $X\in\emptyset$ such that $x\not\in X$, that would be a counterexample - but you can't!") You can similarly justify the second identity.

Note also, if the second identity ("empty union is empty") is easier to "swallow", then you can easily derive the first identity from it using DeMorgan's laws:

$$\bigcap_{X\in\emptyset}X=\left(\bigcup_{X\in\emptyset}X^c\right)^c=\emptyset^c=A$$

Comment: But the defining condition only says that IF $K,L \in \mathfrak S_\alpha$, then $K \cap L \in \mathfrak S_\alpha$. I see no way of deducing facts about the empty family in this context.

Comment: @AlexM. They don't say intersection of *two* sets in $\mathfrak S_\alpha$ is in $\mathfrak S_\alpha$. They say *every intersection*, this includes empty intersections as well as, crucially, infinite intersections.

Comment: Oh, you mean that every $x \in A$ trivially satisfies $x \in \emptyset$ (by the very axiom of the empty set: $x \in \emptyset \iff x \notin \emptyset$)?

Comment: @AlexM. No, **no** $x\in A$ satisfies $x\in\emptyset$. This means, though, that **every** set is in the empty **intersection**.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: As a "working mathematician" I'm trying hard to wrap my mind around all this. Could you please explain why $(\forall X \in \emptyset) \ x \in X$ is vacuously true for all $x \in A$?

Comment: @AlexM. Because there is no counterexample to it. Suppose you give me an $x$; then a counterexample to "$\forall X\in\emptyset(x\in X)$" would be some $X\in\emptyset$ such that $x\not\in X$; do you see why there isn't any?

Comment: @AlexM. It is the *family* of subsets that is empty. There is *no such X* to which $x$ wouldn't belong. So no, nothing belongs to $\emptyset$, neither any $x\in A$, nor any $X\subseteq A$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Let's see: since the axiom of the empty set is $\exists \emptyset \forall x \ \lnot (x \in \emptyset)$, it follows that such an $X$ as the one you assumed to exist does not exist, in fact. Is this it?

Comment: @AlexM. Correct! And with that, there is no chance you can have a counterexample, i.e. a subset $X$ to which a chosen $x$ would *not* belong. That is why it is vacuously true that $x$ belongs to "all" (zero in total ;) ) such subsets $X$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I've decided to accept this answer because its approach and notation proved to be closer to my beginner's understanding. Plus, you already have a huge reputation. I hope that this doesn't bother you. Thank you for your help, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the intersection of the empty family consists of *everything*: $$\bigcap\emptyset=\{x: \forall a\in\emptyset(x\in a)\}=\{x: x=x\}.$$ Now of course there isn't actually a universal set, so this is an abuse of terminology. When we speak of "the intersection of the empty family," we really mean this *in the context of some universal set*: writing "$\bigcap \mathcal{A}_U$" for "$\{x\in U: \forall a\in\mathcal{A}(x\in a)\}$," we have $$\bigcap\emptyset_U=\{x\in U: \forall a\in\emptyset(x\in a)\}=U.$$

*(EDIT: Why is $\bigcap\emptyset_U=U$? Well, take $x\in U$; I claim $x\in\bigcap \emptyset_U$. Otherwise, we would have to have some $X\in\emptyset$ with $x\not\in X$, but there is no $X\in\emptyset$ at all. "$x\in U\implies x\in\bigcap\emptyset_U$" is vacuously true in exactly the same way, but with a little more abstraction, as the sentence "Every flying purple dinosaur is a neo-Kantian" is true. **Universal** quantification over the emptyset yields truth always, and **existential** quantification over the emptyset yields falsity always.)*

The choice of universal set when performing this operation is almost always omitted (and the notation above, or anything like it, never used in my experience) - in my opinion, sadly - on the grounds that it's always clear from context; in this case, it's $E_\alpha.$ Note that "universal set" here is a misnomer, since we're considering lots of different $E_\alpha$s; a better word would be "context," but I feel that the term "universal set" is useful when thinking about what "the empty intersection" should be, at least at first.

---

EDIT: This is how I would write Bourbaki's definition with a bit more precision:

> Suppose $\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$ is a collection of subsets of $E_\alpha$ such that for all $X\subseteq\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$, we have $$\bigcap X_{E_\alpha}\in\mathfrak{S}_\alpha.$$

If we take $X=\emptyset$, then we have $\bigcap X_{E_\alpha}=E_\alpha$ by the reasoning above; since $\emptyset\subseteq\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$ regarldess of what $\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$ is, we get $E_\alpha\in\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$ as desired.

Comment: So, should I understand that Bourbaki silently assumes that $E_\alpha \in \mathfrak S_\alpha$ (i.e. that $E_\alpha$ is "compact")? This was my thought when I read it, too, but then why not say it explicitly? They are usually painfully explicit, hence my doubts.

Comment: @AlexM. No, you don't have to make any assumptions at all besides what I said in my answer. We want $\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$ to be a set of subsets of $E_\alpha$ closed under arbitrary intersections, with the understanding that the universal set in this context is $E_\alpha$. This means that - since $\emptyset\in\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$ no matter what - we must have that $\mathfrak{S}_\alpha$ contains the "empty intersection," which in this case is really $\bigcap\emptyset_{E_\alpha}$. The **only** point of convention is the treatment of the empty intersection.

Comment: @AlexM. I've made a couple edits; hopefully they help.